# Dynamic LINQ filter

Tags: linq

I am using System.Linq.Dynamic and I have following piece of code.

```
var filter = "Id==1 AND Id==2 AND ID==3"; 
var docs= context.Documents.Where(filter);
```

Above code works .
I want to change it to something like

```
var filter = "(new int[]{1,2,3}).Contains(Id)";
var docs= context.Documents.Where(filter);
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: And how are you using the second form of your _filter_? The same way as the first one? Which I have to assume to be raw SQL. You say you want to _change it_ - are you saying you want to change it in the database? Last, you say "doesn't work", which doesn't say much about what happens.

Comment: Filters are stored in my database column .I am using dynamic linq dll to compile the string filters to linq .

Comment: What does "this does not work" mean?

Comment: I have improved the question , please remove down-vote or let me know what else correction required . I am unable to post questions due to down-votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Linq.Dynamic` documentation says:

```
The expression language supports integer, real, string, and character literals.
```

So Array literals are not supported.

Also, `Contains` is not listed as being supported.

See the [Dynamic Expressions](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions) documentation.